# Edge WebDriver Version

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

How to you tell which version of Edge web driver you are using?

I want to use the web driver Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363

as instructed here I did this to get the Webdriver

"Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt: DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0"

I am using selenium with java, I have tests working with chrome browser selenium and I access the web driver by using .exe file however no .exe file was provided, or I am unaware where it was install. I looked in the directory I was in when I ran the command above and no exe was found.

please advise on how i can connect to the web driver using java and selenium.

Comment: You said "as instructed here" but there's no link or information about where you got that instruction. Have you been to Microsoft's site? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' at`C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with the suggestion given by @supputuri.

You can also directly reference the path in a code like below. It will also work.

Example:

```
package selenium_test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class new_java_class 
{

        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

                  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32\\\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

                  WebDriver browser = new EdgeDriver();

                  browser.get("https://microsoft.com");               
        }
}
```